# Bitmap copy in camera folder

Tags: android, bitmap, storage, external

I'm having an odd problem on saving my bitmap image that I got from a LayoutView. The code below creates the bitmap and should export as an image to the palettes folder on the SD card. It actually does that, but there is also a duplicate copy of the bitmap in my Camera folder when I open up the Gallery app. Is there a way I can just copy into the folder alone without having a duplicate in the Camera folder? Also if there was a way you can delete the same copy in the Camera folder, that would work too. Thanks!

```
LinearLayout paletteView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ExportBitmapLayout);
paletteView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
paletteView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = paletteView.getDrawingCache();

String filename = "PALETTETITLE";
filename.toLowerCase();
filename.replace(" ","_");
filename = filename.substring(0, (filename.length() < 30) ? filename.length() : 29);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, filename);

boolean created = createDirIfNotExists("palettes");

if (created)
    Log.i("Directory created","OK");    
else
    Log.i("Directory exists","OK");

//if successful
try 
{
    OutputStream fOut = null;

    String longString = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "palettes" +File.separator + filename+".jpg";

    File f = new File(longString);
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(f);

    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);

    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();

    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), f.getAbsolutePath(), filename, filename);

    Context context = ExportMenuImageActivity.this.getApplicationContext();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Image saved to Gallery! NOTE: Unintentional save in Camera folder. Fix in next update.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {longString}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() 
    {   
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) 
        {
        }
    });


}

catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Arzeimuth, if you have got the solution of your problem.then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Here is the complete solution of your problem.You can not do anything like protecting the camera folder to save images. But you can delete the latest image jsut after your image inserted inside the database.

Here is the code for deleting the latest file from the camera folder, Just do copy and paste it and call this method whenever you want to delete the latest file from you camera folder..


private void deleteLatest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera" );

        //Log.i("Log", "file name in delete folder :  "+f.toString());
        File [] files = f.listFiles();

        //Log.i("Log", "List of files is: " +files.toString());
        Arrays.sort( files, new Comparator<Object>()
                {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

                if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
                    //         Log.i("Log", "Going -1");
                    return -1;
                } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
                    //     Log.i("Log", "Going +1");
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    //     Log.i("Log", "Going 0");
                    return 0;
                }
            }

                });

        //Log.i("Log", "Count of the FILES AFTER DELETING ::"+files[0].length());
        files[0].delete();

    }

If still you have any query then let me know!!!
Cheers...
```

Comment: Actually while doing some more debugging, I found a small issue. Your method of sorting and deleting works fine, and the file is deleted in the Camera folder when I look in the File Explorer. However, there is still a thumbnail preview in the Gallery in the Camera folder. How would I go upon deleting the thumbnail? Thanks again!

Comment: hi Arzeimuth, whn i am doing so,i am not facing any problem wth it.but let me check 1ce agn,if i l get the solution of this. i wil definitely let you know.

Comment: Hey nick, I have found a solution to my problem. All I have to do is remove the MediaStore statement. Apparently, it stores my file onto my camera folder, regardless of the path which is stated to another folder. Anyhow, thanks for help!